# how to adjust CSS margin-left in my navigation

Tags: css, navigation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMrRy.jpg)

Can somebody help me? I want to adjust my margin in my navigation menu. I have tried to adjust my margin-left to all of available navigaton elements but it is not working.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  background: black;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <nav class="main_nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Post a question</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

is this output you are expecting? check output in jsbin link

[Jsbin link](http://jsbin.com/wicene/edit?html,output)

***CODE***

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    nav {
        background: black;
       
    }
    
    nav ul li {
        list-style: none;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 5px;
       margin-left:-25px;
       margin-right:25px;
    }
    
    nav ul li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
    
    }
    
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="container">
    
                <nav class="main_nav">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Post a question</a></li>
                        </ul>
    
                </nav>[enter image description here][1]
            </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: please see sample picture. I want to adjust the nav or home to left side

Comment: Thanks! it's working now... but why do i have to set margin-left to negative(-) pixels? and why is margin-left in positive value does not work?

Comment: -ve value moves the element to left side